# files name with c++

Tags: c++, filenames, printf

in c++, for edit many files I use some similar to

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char nombre[10];
    int i;
    ofstream salida;

    for (i = 10; i < 20; i++) {
        sprintf(nombre,"archivo%d.txt",i);
        cout << nombre<<endl;
        salida.open(nombre);
        salida << 1000*i << endl;
        salida.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

exist a better c++ way? for no use a `char[10]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the C++ `std::ostringstream` type:

```
for (int i = 10; i < 20; i++) {
    std::ostringstream filename;
    filename << "archivo" << i << ".txt";
    salida.open(filename.str().c_str());
       /* ... */
    salida.close();
}
```

Most uses of `sprintf` can be replaced by `std::ostringstream`.  You will need to include the `<sstream>` header file for this to work, though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: but is it better? `nobre` sits comfortly on stack, sprintf does it's age-optimized job, and now, you introduce additional header, additional stack object, object creation overhead and it looks `ugly` too. Are there any proven time benchmarks? I am just curious..

Comment: @Ulterior- The OP's question wasn't about efficiency (I think).  I wouldn't worry about the performance of the string building; the disk I/O is going to take orders of magnitude more time anyway.

Comment: @Ulterior: Very few C++ approaches are better for run time efficiency  than C, but most code isn't time critical.  Using standard library classes like ostringstream tend to make things more robust and maintainable - e.g. if I'm reading the OP's code correctly, it's actually corrupting the stack already, since "archivo10.txt" is more than 10 characters.  Correct code is usually better than fast code.  That being said, one obviously has to think about the cost/benefit in any given situation.

Comment: @happydave +1 for stack corruption, didn't notice it :)

Comment: You can also use [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are just looking for the c++ string class.

It can be found in `std::string`.

[This is a pretty good reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

Here you would use the string as:

```
#include <sstream>

...{ 
    std::string fileName = "archivo";
    std::string extension = ".txt";

    ...

    salida.open((fileName + NumberToString(i) + extension).c_str()); 

    ...
}

template <typename T>
string NumberToString ( T Number )
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << Number;
    return ss.str();
}
```

The above is was recommended [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/9645/).

Comment: The C++ string type does not do conversions from integer types.  You need a separate piece of code to do that.

Comment: std::string(atoi(yourCharStar))

Comment: You should probably post that as part of the question.  Otherwise someone might think that writing `std::string s = "filename" + i;` is going to do the right thing, which would be Bad Times.

Comment: Okay, I added some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

[boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/format/) would be very convenient replacement of sprintf. If this is what you are looking for.

Comment: boost don't is installed in all computers

Comment: well, then the best answer is what templatetypedef suggests. But really, boost is very useful if you want to program in c++.